# sql like matches to different characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode

There is Unicode character [¹] - Superscript One (in Latin-1 Supplement block):

```
SELECT NCHAR(0x00b9) --returns ¹
```

But trying to find out is that symbols exist in column next query returns rows which contain digit one (0x0031):

```
SELECT [Name] FROM [Company] WHERE [Name] like '%'+nchar(0x00b9)+'%'
```

**Update:** I am using MSSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your database has a Case INsensitive Collation:

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX (DB_NAME(DB_ID()), 'COLLATION') -- = Latin1_General_CI_AS

SELECT [Name] AS [WHERE_Collation caseINsensitive] 
FROM   ( VALUES  ('¹')
              ,  ('1') ) AS Company (Name) 
WHERE [Name] LIKE '%'+nchar(0x00b9)+'%' 
;
```

Result:

WHERE_Collation caseINsensitive

¹

1

```
SELECT [Name] AS [Collation caseSensitive] 
FROM   ( VALUES  ('¹')
              ,  ('1') ) AS Company (Name) 
WHERE [Name] LIKE '%'+nchar(0x00b9)+'%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
;
```

Result

WHERE_Collation caseSensitive

¹

Comment: Thanks you for your answer